# php artisan migrate command error, could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, wamp, laravel-7, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to connect my laravel app to my MySql database but i get this error, I' using wamp server on windows, i've tried pretty much everything i can find on the internet but to no avail, I should mention that few days before i started this project i unistalled some C++ Redistributables, u will find a picture of what i currently have installed, im not sure if its relative to this problem. please check it out.

this is the error i get :

```
$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_sc
hema = todos_app and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\Super user\Desktop\LEARNING\PFA\todos-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src
\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll for
mat the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this e
xception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's
 errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\Users\Super user\Desktop\LEARNING\PFA\todos-app\vendor\laravel\framework\sr
c\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\Users\Super user\Desktop\LEARNING\PFA\todos-app\vendor\laravel\framework\sr
c\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

This is my .env file :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:rPySRRDMuul88x4+ihTqOiD0PPCN2bOmugjFi41bDvY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=todos_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=letmein

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

This is my database.php file :

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3308'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'todos_app'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'letmein'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

This is my [php.ini](https://pastebin.com/MGM6MhBt) file thats in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin folder

[what i currently have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veLtr.png)

Thnks for ur time

Comment: Your php.ini looks a bit odd, there's `extension=pdo_mysql` and also `extension=pdo_mysql.dll` and `extension=mysql.so` I think if this is on windows all of these need to end in `.dll`

Comment: yeah i got frustrated and was trying anything and everything, i didnt notice the .so extension, i removed it, still the problem presists

Comment: Are you sure about `DB_PORT=3308`? Try to set it to 3306. If that doesn't do the trick, try `'strict' => false,` I had some issues with strict set to true before. Wamp has a manager no? Can you access mysql from there? This doesn't seem to be a Laravel settings problem. Maybe reinstall wamp, your config files are conserved.

Comment: i tried both 3308 and 3306 for the port, and switched strict value to false, nothing worked, so i unistalled wamp and was about to install again but i decided to try Appserve instead and it worked perfectly. thnks for the tips.